# Finding slope from a 2D Plot

Tags: plotting, education

Imagine I have a set of data, the plot is as following(just as an example consider a Gaussian curve):
[image]

Is there any way to obtain the slop of this curve slop and plotted just using the initial data.

Thank alot

Comment: Do you have some example data?

Comment: And explain please, what is "the first plot in Mathematica"?

Comment: @  Alexei Boulbitch I added an example, also by first data I meant the data I plotted the curve.

Comment: @Coolwater I added an example.

Comment: I want to plot the slop of this curve with his own data, is it possible?

Comment: What is the underlying data?
Step 1: fit the curve to produce the function.
Step 2: take the derivative of your fitted function.
Step 3: plot the derivative.

Comment: "Data"?  There's no data here.  A function (such as $\sin x$) is not "data."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to do it numerically with a dataset, say `data`

```
data = Table[{x, Exp[-x^2]}, {x, -5, 5, 0.1}];
```

you can go like this

```
ndata = Length[data];
slope = Table[{(data[[i, 1]] + data[[i - 1, 1]])/2, 
               (data[[i, 2]] - data[[i - 1, 2]])/(data[[i, 1]] - data[[i - 1, 1]]) },
              {i, 2, ndata}];
ListLinePlot[{data, slope}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Or you can go with [`Interpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html)

```
f[x_] = Interpolation[data][x]; (*function for data*)
f1[x_] = D[f[x], x];            (*function for derivative*)
Plot[{f[x], f1[x]}, {x, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for something the same as the second part of your answer

Comment: In case you know any trial function for your data, you can also use [`Fit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fit.html), [`FindFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFit.html) or [`NonlinearModelFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html) to find a functional form.